# При передвижении метки на карте в рамках одного дома - меняется адрес, теряется улица

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

При передвижении метки на карте в рамках одного дома - меняется адрес, теряется улица, координаты точки передаются корректные, если их забить в яндекс карту к примеру- выдается правильный результат - с улицей. Как уточнить геокодирование в этом случае?

```
if (!address) {
            // Ищем по геокодеру яндекса
            await ymaps.geocode(coords, { kind: "house" }).then(function (res) {
                var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);

                console.log(firstGeoObject, "...firstGeoObject...");

                /** nice format of returned address */
                if (firstGeoObject) {
                    resultObj.city =
                        firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length > 0
                            ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities()[0]
                            : "";
                    resultObj.area =
                        firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas().length > 0
                            ? firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas()[0]
                            : "";
                    resultObj.secondArea =
                        firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas().length > 1
                            ? firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas()[1]
                            : "";
                    resultObj.street = firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare()
                        ? firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare()
                        : "";
                    resultObj.house = firstGeoObject.getPremiseNumber()
                        ? firstGeoObject.getPremiseNumber()
                        : "";
                    resultObj.coords = coords;
                    resultObj.block = "";

                    if (resultObj.house) {
                        result = [
                            resultObj.area,
                            resultObj.city,
                            resultObj.street,
                            resultObj.house,
                            resultObj.block,
                        ]; // [area, secondArea, city, street, house]
                        result = [...new Set(result.filter(Boolean))];

                        self.mapElement.dispatchEvent(
                            new CustomEvent("address-selected-checkout", {
                                detail: { result, resultObj, zoneName },
                            })
                        );

                        address = result.join(", ");

                        console.log(address, "...try with house");
                        console.log(
                            resultObj.coords,
                            "...try with house resultObj.coords"
                        );
                    }
                }
                console.log("Yandex geocode try with house");

                /** or just uncomment next line */
                // vm.selectedAddress = firstGeoObject.getAddressLine();
            });
        }
```

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWJEA.jpg)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите конкретные примеры проблемных адресов. Также будут полезны скринкаст проблемы или логи запросов с объяснениями. Текущее описание проблемы недостаточно полное для анализа.